# Is there a way to not refresh the iframe each time i change tabs?

Tags: c#, jquery, iframe

I have jquery tabs on my page, each tab has a single iframe in it.  Everything works, except... 
The iframes refresh each time I switch tabs.

The source for the Iframes is set in the Page_Load and is only executed once.  The jquery does not do anything except change the tab...no other code.

Is there a way to not refresh the iframe each time?

Comment: how you have configured jquery tabs..its a client side so switching tabs will never make a postback to server which means page never refreshes..refer api.jqueryui.com/tabs

Comment: Does it happen in all browsers?

Comment: I'm only using IE8, but I tried it in Chrome Frame as well and got the same result.  Vishal...I know the current page isn't refreshing, but the iframes source page are, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why I never want to ask anything on this site...I know it's gonna be something simple, but for anyone that may be helped in the future from my pain...

In the code for the jquery tabs to select or hide tabs, I had a call to a button click event that was used to keep track of the current state of the tabs.  This is what caused the postback and why my iframes were getting reinstantiated.

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var sel = ui.index;

            $("[id*=SelectedTab]").val(sel);
            $("[id*=ChangeTabButton]").click();
        },
        selected: $("[id*=SelectedTab]").val()
    });
});
```

Thanks Kevin and Vishal...